# Using Google Cloud Print in Android

Tags: android, google-cloud-print

I am using google cloud print with an android project to print out a pdf file. I am storing the file in the assets folder of the project and when I go to print it say "Document Missing".

Here is my code

```
public void stevePrint(View view) {
    Intent printIntent = new Intent(this, PrintDialogActivity.class);
    //Cant find file, why?
    File file = new File("/assets/steve.pdf");
    printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "document/pdf");
    printIntent.putExtra("title", "Steve");
    startActivity(printIntent);

    Context context = getApplicationContext();
    CharSequence text = "Sending to Google Cloud Print";
    int duration = Toast.LENGTH_LONG;

    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(context, text, duration);
    toast.show();
}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Does file.exists() return true?

Answer (score 9):

You appear to be using the wrong MIME type. It should read:

```
printIntent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/pdf");
```

It looks like you're using PrintDialogActivity, [from the Google Cloud Print documentation](https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/android). Make sure to also add the `@JavascriptInterface` annotations to each method inside `PrintDialogJavaScriptInterface`.

Comment: This should be marked as the answer. Also if anyone happens to be able to run cloud print but the print button won't work, please make sure to import android.webkit.JavascriptInterface; and add the @JavascriptInterface as stated by Paul. I have been seeking how to solve that for weeks. It's easy to overlook. Thank you very much Paul!

Comment: Done trying all the above things.. Still getting the same issue of Document Missing. Can some body get help me on this.